# Unable to create new connection in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm new and just started Oracle. I installed Oracle SQL Developer[Version: 19.2.1.247] and now I want create new connection but I'm not able to create and found an error like :

```
Status : Failure -Test failed: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied.
```

I am sure about I didn't made a mistake into entered wrong or incorrect credential. if I am so please tell me about that and also tell me the solution to solve this error.

check attachment below.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a **database** to connect to? SQL Developer is just a *tool* to access the database; it is not the database itself. Apart from that, error says that you provided invalid credentials. Mind letter case.

Comment: Yes, I have already installed database first. Apart Form that, I didn't made mistake into entered credential. I tried twice once manual and second time did copy paste and in second type there is no chance of case sensitive.   @Littlefoot

Answer (score 0):

Well your error message is straight forward. The connection details (username & password) are incorrect. The solution for this error is simple --> enter the correct credentials.

Now, you said that you have installed SQL-Developer. SQL-Developer is just a tool (program/software) used for accessing a Database. In this case, my question would be: do you have a database to which you want to connect to? Based on your screenshot, I see that you are using the default HOSTNAME/SID/PORT, meaning that you either forgot to enter your Database details or you created a username on your local Database (created when you have installed ORACLE Client and followed all those instructions).

If you are trying to connect to an already created Database, make sure that the HOSTNAME/PORT/SID are the ones belonging to the Database and not the standard one.

If you created a username on your local database, then you either forgot your password or you used some invalid characters which can no longer be used right now. Try resetting the password of that user, using another user (via ALTER USER) or using the SQL Developer (right click - Reset Password) with your old password.

Comment: I Already Installed database first. I didn't made a mistake into entered credential and password is also so simple there is no invalid character which no longer used. HOSTNAME/PORT/SID this are also right and its work before some time and successfully created connection too. I just uninstall database and install again I face this error.

Comment: And have you configured your sysdb user when installing the Oracle Client? Because you can use that user to reset the password of your edadmin user and solve your issue.

Comment: all things are good no need to any changes it work before two days. but today it's working.

Comment: well your error message is straight forward --> your credentials are incorrect. Try reseting the password. Use the sysdb user to check your account status in " select * From SYS.dba_users; " Maybe your account got locked and SQL Developer doesn't show you that your account is locked / or your passwod is expired.

Comment: My account status is open and password also not expired.

Comment: ok in that case, reset the password. It is your only option, from my point of view.

Comment: Passwords are case sensitive, the other possibility is you're connecting to a different database than you think you are

Comment: Sir 1st I simply installed Oracle Database and now I want to create one connection but that is showing me error so where I wrote this above query and all I have already Script but 1st I want to create Database Connection that I execute the script and query.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith in copy and pasting of  Username and password there is no chance of case sensitive.

Comment: Then you're not connecting to the right database

Comment: Is this a pluggable database? If so, orcl SID will be the container, you'll need to use the pdb service name in your connection properties